# Google Analytics redirect to provision page issue

Tags: google, google-analytics

I cannot register in Analytics. I will be redirected to the page below:

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/#/provision
```

I even used another browser and browser private mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was happening to me too. I didn't realize until now that the 'sign up for free' button on that page is actually there, but in white.

[image: Screenshot of button]